# Mapping NHibernate Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to map a legacy database here and I'm running into a problem. In my schema I have a concept of Modules and a concept of Variables.  Each Module consists of one or more Variables and each of these Variables has properties specific to that Module. A Varable sits on a Relation.

Based on the classes below what is the best way to map ModuleVariable which looks, to me, like a many-to-many relationship with special properties??

Here are the classes:

```
public class Relation
{
    public virtual string RelationId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Variable
{
    public virtual string VariableId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Relation RelationId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
} 

public class Module
{
    public virtual string ModuleId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ModuleVariable
{       
    public virtual Module ModuleId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Variable VariableId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Relation RelationId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Variable DownloadID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Variable UploadID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Repeatable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would get better help if you also posted a sample schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a many-to-many relationship with extra properties on the relationship like that, you'll have to make `ModuleVariable` a domain entity and map it separately from `Module` and `Variable`.

`Module` and `Variable` will have a collection of `ModuleVariable` entities and `ModuleVariable` will have a many-to-one reference to the other two. Something like:

```
<!-- Module mapping -->
<bag name="ModuleVariables" inverse="true">
    <key column="Module_id" />
    <one-to-many class="ModuleVariable" />
</bag>

<!-- ModuleVariable mapping -->
<many-to-one name="Module" column="Module_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The many-to-many only works on table with no extra properties.
This because many-to-many represents a collection of items inside of other entity.

If your table ModuleVariable does not have others columns, you could use like that:

```
<bag name="Modules" table="MODULE_VARIABLE" cascade="save-update" lazy="true" >
  <key>
    <column name="Variable_Id" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="Module">
    <column name="Module_Id" not-null="true"/>
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

And in your domain classes:

```
public IList Modules { get; set; }
```

And for use, you should Add the modules:

```
variable.Modules.Add(module);
```

Hopes to help.